# For a private variable, how do you write a Junit test case

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

Whenever I try to execute this code, I get NullPointerException for this variable effectiveEndDate

```
@Component
public class CustomerCommodityMarkupMapService 
{
     @Value("${default.effective.endDate}")
     private String effectiveEndDate;

     public CommodityMarkup mapMarkupModelToEntity(CommodityMarkupView commodityMarkupView) 
     {
         CommodityMarkup commodityMarkup = new CommodityMarkup();
     commodityMarkup.setEffectiveEndDate(DateTimeUtil.convertStringToDate(effectiveEndDate));
}
```

```
@Test
void testMapMarkupModelToEntity() 
{
    CustomerCommodityMarkup mappedMarkup = new CustomerCommodityMarkup();
    String effectiveEndDate = "12/31/9999";
    if (effectiveEndDate != null) 
    {
        commodityMarkup.setEffectiveEndDate(DateTimeUtil.convertStringToDate(effectiveEndDate));
    }
    CustomerCommodityMarkup actualMarkup =      customerCommodityMarkupMapService.mapMarkupModelToEntity(commodityMarkupView);
    assertEquals(mappedMarkup, actualMarkup);
}
```

Comment: How do you get that service? Did you set the property value in the test properties or test setup?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using property injection by putting the `@Value` annotation to the property, use rather constructor injection like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomerCommodityMarkupMapService {

     private final String effectiveEndDate;

     public CustomerCommodityMarkupMapService(@Value("${default.effective.endDate}") String effectiveEndDate) {
          this.effectiveEndDate = effectiveEndDate;
     }
}
```

You will be able to set the value in your unit test.

If you need to access a private property in your test, you can always use reflection, but it's kind of a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

We can override properties by putting the property file in the test resources. This file must be on the same classpath as the default one.

It should contain all the property keys specified in the default file. Therefore, we'll add the `application.properties` file into the `src/test/resources`.

It will override value.

You can refer [here](https://Now%20we%27ll%20override%20properties%20by%20putting%20the%20property%20file%20in%20the%20test%20resources.%20This%20file%20must%20be%20on%20the%20same%20classpath%20as%20the%20default%20one.%20%20Additionally,%20it%20should%20contain%20all%20the%20property%20keys%20specified%20in%20the%20default%20file.%20Therefore,%20we%27ll%20add%20the%20application.properties%20file%20into%20the%20src/test/resources:).

Comment: The OP is using unit tests, not integration tests, judging by the way he instantiates the service using constructor. `application.properties` won't work, for that he needs Spring Integration Tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection to inject value here. For example like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mappedMarkup, "effectiveEndDate", "12/31/9999");
}
```

Or you can use it directly inside test just call like this after object is constructed:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mappedMarkup, "effectiveEndDate", "12/31/9999");
```

It should help you.